# Windows install after Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

saw the tutorials on here on how to do this but this is what I've come across.
both windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 as of right now work just fine,
I read I would have to fix grub and all that jazz but nothing of the sort happened

I put windows on a second hard rive the only problem I'm having is I can only enter windows by hitting F11 at bios ....any fix for that?

Comment: In Ubuntu, try running `sudo update-grub`. Hopefully, it will find the second hdd, and detect the Windows installation there. If successful, you should see Grub menu on boot with options to select from.

Comment: DUDE, thanks a million wish you posted it as an answer so I could mark it as a solution THANKS. ...lol something so simple but it worked

Comment: I'll post an answer, ..glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a BIOS unlock, you might be able to choose which bootloader is default from each drive. In other words BIOS unlock allows you to set BBS priorities for each drive. Even for multiple OSs in your external USB flash drive should show up. Also you will have to disable Secure Boot permanently if you do the BIOS update as it will break your current GRUB signature and won't let you boot to it. If you install Ubuntu after BIOS update then it might work with Secure Boot

TIP: You will have to permanently disable Windows Fast Startup since if it is enabled you wont be able to write to any internal disk from within Ubuntu as Windows saves the session to the disk, and Linux will not be able to mount it as R/W. only R/O.

GRUB still doesn't detect Windows Boot Manager, but maybe you can manually enter it in grub config but I didn't try it. You now have Windows as first priority in RAID BBS priority so you don't have to press F11 to boot to Windows and when you want to boot Ubuntu you press F11 and choose that. You can choose defaults from BIOS.

But the F-11 option is a must for now. You just have to choose what OS you want for default boot.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, try running `sudo update-grub`. Hopefully, it will find the second hdd, and detect the Windows installation there. If successful, you should see Grub menu on boot with options to select from.